# Take a Function from outside then run and take value

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to take from outside A function that like "Future<List?> Function(String userId)" then use it, but this error appear, this tell me I try to     "equalize" (if this word don't fit please edit, and title is not fitted), No I dont want to equalize, I just want to run this function and take value. You can run this code on https://dartpad.dev/?

### [image]

```
 A value of type 'Future<List<String>?> Function(String)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<String>?'.
    Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<String>?'.
```

--

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef getAllProducts = Future<List<String>?> Function(String userId); 

class AdanaView extends StatefulWidget {
 const AdanaView({Key? key, required this.getProducts}) : super(key: key);
  final getAllProducts getProducts;

  @override
  State<AdanaView> createState() => _AdanaViewState();
}

class _AdanaViewState extends State<AdanaView> {
   List<String>? products;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAll();
  }

  Future<void> getAll() async {
    products = await widget.getProducts;
    setState(() {});
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Adana'),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to call the function `products = await widget.getProducts('some-user-id-here');`

Comment: is it possible take "some-user-id-here" with Function or I have to take separately

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You defined `typedef getAllProducts = Future<List<String>?> Function(String userId);`, so clearly it takes a `userId` as an argument.

Comment: Mybad, just got a little confused, thanks for your help, I did what I wanted to do thanks to  you.